# Exporting Chess moves and images into HTML or CSV format

Tags: python, html, export-to-csv, chess, python-chess

I have used the post ([Printing individual moves with the python-chess library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517471/printing-individual-moves-with-the-python-chess-library/63520025#63520025)) to obtain the individual moves and display image of the chess board. See the code below.

```
import chess
from io import StringIO
import chess.pgn

#create a virtual board
board = chess.Board()    
#Paste PGN data    
pgn_string = """
1 e4 e6 2 d4 c6 3 Nf3 Nf6 4 Bg5 h6 5 Bf4 Na6 6 Bc4 d5 7 Bd3 Nxe4 8 O-O Nb4 9 Ne5 a5 
10 Qg4 f5 11 Qg6+ Ke7 12 Qf7+ Kd6 13 Nc4# 
"""

# Converting the string into StringIO object
pgn = StringIO(pgn_string)
# Reading the game
game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn) 
#Printing and displaying the moves in algebraic notation
for move in game.mainline_moves():
        print(board.san(move))
        board.push(move)
        display(board)
```

I am able to obtain the output (see the image below) in jupyter for each moves and their corresponding board image (inside a scrolled window in jupyter)
[image]

I am trying to figure out if the above data (i.e individual move and their image) can be exported to HTML or CSV format, so that i can analyse the moves, as it is difficult to analyze in jupyter. Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you have in `move`? If you have text then you can write it in file(inside this loop)  or append to some list and later write all in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `board.san(move)` gives current move as text and you can keep it on list to save it later.

In documentation I found function [chess.svg.board()](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/svg.html) which generates string with `SVG image` - and you can save in file using standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()`

Every browser can display image `svg` in HTML

You need only loop to create HTML with all moves and images

```
import chess
import chess.pgn
from io import StringIO

board = chess.Board()    

pgn_string = """
1 e4 e6 2 d4 c6 3 Nf3 Nf6 4 Bg5 h6 5 Bf4 Na6 6 Bc4 d5 7 Bd3 Nxe4 8 O-O Nb4 9 Ne5 a5 
10 Qg4 f5 11 Qg6+ Ke7 12 Qf7+ Kd6 13 Nc4# 
"""

pgn = StringIO(pgn_string)

game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn) 

steps = []
for number, move in enumerate(game.mainline_moves()):
    text = board.san(move) 
    print(text)
    
    # keep current step on list
    steps.append(text)

    board.push(move)
    #display(board)

    # create string with SVG image
    svg = chess.svg.board(board)
    
    # save string in file with name `board-0.svg`, `board-1.svg`, etc.
    with open(f'board-{number}.svg', 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(svg)
    
# --- after loop ---

#print(steps)

# create string with HTML

html = ""

for number, move in enumerate(steps):
    # add move
    html += f'{move}</br>\n'
    
    # add image `board-0.svg`, `board-1.svg`, etc. (with width=300 to make it smaller)
    html += f'<img src="board-{number}.svg" width="300"></br>\n'
    
# save html in file    
with open('index.html', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(html)
```

Screenshot from web browser:

[image]

---

**BTW:**

It needs files `board-0.svg`, `board-1.svg`, etc. to display it but  you may also put string directly in HTML.

```
import chess
import chess.pgn
from io import StringIO

board = chess.Board()    

pgn_string = """
1 e4 e6 2 d4 c6 3 Nf3 Nf6 4 Bg5 h6 5 Bf4 Na6 6 Bc4 d5 7 Bd3 Nxe4 8 O-O Nb4 9 Ne5 a5 
10 Qg4 f5 11 Qg6+ Ke7 12 Qf7+ Kd6 13 Nc4# 
"""

pgn = StringIO(pgn_string)

game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn) 

steps = []
for number, move in enumerate(game.mainline_moves()):
    text = board.san(move) 
    print(text)
    
    board.push(move)
    #display(board)

    # create string with SVG image (with size=300 to make it smaller)
    svg = chess.svg.board(board, size=300)

    # keep current step [text, svg] on list
    steps.append( [text, svg])

# --- after loop ---

#print(steps)

# create string with HTML

html = ""

for number, (text, svg) in enumerate(steps):
    # add move
    html += f'{text}</br>\n'

    # add image
    html += f'{svg}</br>\n'
    
# save html in file    
with open('index.html', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(html)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried the loop to export in csv, but I could not export the image.. i was missing the svg idea, which you have brilliantly resolved!.. Thanks a ton

Comment: BTW: it seems `chess.svg.board()` has options to display more details - like previous position, arrow with move, etc.